# "To comprehend x, it is necessary to understand y." Is this a dangling modifier?

Tags: modifiers, dangling-modifiers

Because I often think of sentences in the "we must"-form, as in:

"To comprehend x, we must first understand y."

when I write things that demand I do not write "we," I instead often write sentences like this:

"To comprehend x, it is necessary to understand y?"

Is this a dangling modifier? Or is it wrong or ugly in some other way?

Comment: Perhaps whoever is imposing on you the rule against first-person pronouns would prefer (and deserves) the nominalized version: "Comprehension of x is only possible on the basis of an understanding of y."

Comment: You could use "one must" instead of "we must"; you don't need to, but it might satisfy those with a grudge against first person pronouns.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> 'To comprehend X' is a deleted version of say 'If we are to be able to comprehend X' and with the fuller version (this fuller version, at least) we see that there is a 'we' missing from the independent clause. The missing words could equally be 'one' and 'one'. So a purist could argue that there is a problem. However, 'It is necessary to understand Y to [be able to] comprehend X' would raise few eyebrows (other than for word-choice): no one would think to look for missing agents. I'd say your original, merely a re-ordering, is fine (other than that it may offend the odd hyperprescriptivist).

Answer (score 0):

> "To comprehend x, we must first understand y."

"To comprehend x" is an abbreviated, fronting adverbial. The complete version is

"**In order** to comprehend x, we must first understand y."

which itself can be uninverted:

"We must first understand y **in order** to comprehend x."

"in order to" is an adverbial. "comprehend x" is a noun phrase as a complement.

OED

> P3 **in order to** b. (b) **With infinitive expressing purpose: so as to do or achieve (some end or outcome).**
>
> 1609   Bible (Douay) I. Exod. vi. 27   These are they that speak to Pharao, king of Egypt, in order to bring out the children of Israel from Egypt.
>
> 1994   Food & Wine Oct. 74 (caption)    True risotto must be stirred continuously in order to develop its unique texture.

Comment: Generally known as a purpose infinitive, if it passes the _in order to_ test.